# Button onclick method not passing element id

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've been attempting to dynamically generate a list of buttons on a page, each of them with an onclick method that passes their id (this.id). I know I can access the method itself, as I had tested a version of it without any parameters.

The specific flow of the code is as follows: My app makes a call to an API (Spotify), and gets back a list of data objects (playlists, in this case) as well as an access code. Then, it adds a button to the page for each object, with the onclick method `getData(this.id)`. This method is included in a separate javascript file, where it is meant to receive this id, make *another* call to the API using the aforementioned access code, and then hide the button with the specified id. However, absolutely nothing happens when you click one of the playlist buttons. The relevant code is below. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

***Client.js***

```
if (hash.access_token) {
      $('#login_jumb').hide();
      $.get({url: '/nextpage', headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${hash.access_token}`}}, function(data) {
        // "Data" is the array of track objects we get from the API. See server.js for the function that returns it.
        console.log(data)

        var title = $('<h3 class="display-4">Your public Spotify playlists:</h3>');
        title.prependTo('#data-container');

        var tracks = new Array(data.items.length);
        // For each of the playlists, create an element
        data.items.forEach(function(playlist) {
          var playlistDiv = $('<button class="btn btn-dark button-pad " id="new"></button>');
          playlistDiv.text(playlist.name);
          playlistDiv.appendTo('#data-container ul');
          document.getElementById("new").id = playlist.name;

          var button = document.getElementById(playlist.name);
          button.setAttribute("onclick","getData(this.id)");
          button.title = button.id;
        });

      });
    }
```

***Retrieve-data.js***

```
    function getData(id) {
            var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

            $.get({url: '/getdata', headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}}, function(data) {
                console.log(id);

                document.getElementById(id).hide();

              });
        }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console when you click on the button?

Comment: Try using this instead `\`getData(${this.id})\``. Currently you're not passing the value of the button. Also, I can't help but notice that you seem to create multiple buttons with the same id `#new`

Comment: @JonathanHamel Alright, I'll try that. And I update the ID to the specific playlist ID a few lines down.

Comment: @JonathanHamel Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Barmar None at all

Comment: `hide()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method.

Comment: never use setAttribute to add events. Use addEventListener

Comment: @Barmar Yup... you're right, not a DOM method. That was the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `button.setAttribute("onclick","getData(this.id)");` and add this  outside of your condition block

```
$(document).on("click", '#data-container button', function (e) {
    const id = $(this).attr('id')

    getData(id)
});
```

As you append a virtual element, you should refere to the document object to listen to the new element event

Comment: While this may be a better way to do it, the original method should work as well.